# Induction principle on proving an inequality

Tags: cv.complex-variables

If $P(z)$ having no zeros in $|z|<1,$ then 
$$\frac{\max_{|z|=1}|P'(z)|}{\max_{|z|=1}|P(z)|}\leq \frac{n}{2}.$$
Can we prove this by induction on $n$? or is there any alternative way?

---

Attempt at a proof: let us try to show that the inequality holds by induction on the degree $n$ of the polynomial  $P(z)$.

If $n=1$ then $P(z)=z-w$ with $|w|\geq 1$, and we have
$$\displaystyle\frac{\max_{|z|=1}|P'(z)|}{\max_{|z|=1}|P(z)|}=\frac{1}{1+|w|}\leq \frac{1}{1+1},$$
which is nothing but the given inequality when $n=1$.

Let $Q(z)=(z-w)P(z)$ with $|w|\geq 1$, where $P(z)$ is a polynomial of  degree $n$ having all its zeros in $|z|\geq 1$. 
 $$\displaystyle\frac{\max_{|z|=1}|Q'(z)|}{\max_{|z|=1}|Q(z)|}=\frac{\max_{|z|=1}|(z-w)P'(z)+P(z)|}{\max_{|z|=1}|(z-w)P(z)|}$$
   \begin{equation}\label{p1}\displaystyle\leq\frac{\max_{|z|=1}|P'(z)|}{\max_{|z|=1}|P(z)|}+\frac{1}{\max_{|z|=1}|z-w|} (?).\end{equation}

Thus the proof by induction will be  complete once we establish (?) part of the above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement is known in the literature as the **Theorem of Erdős and Lax**.

It was conjectured by Erdős and first proved by Lax. Later additional proofs were given by de Bruijn, Aziz--Mohammad, Rahman, and Boas. The proofs of these authors do not use induction.

1. A. Aziz and Q. G. Mohammad: [*Simple Proof of a Theorem of Erdős and Lax*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2042156?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **80**, no. 1 (1980), 119--122
2. R. P. Boas: [Inequalities for asymmetric entire functions](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255378506), Illinois J. Math. **1**, no. 1 (1957), 94--97
3. N. G. de Bruijn: *Inequalities concerning polynomials in the complex domain*, Indag. Math. **9** (1947), 591--598
4. P. D. Lax: [*Proof of a conjecture of P. Erdős on the derivative of a polynomial*](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1944-50-08/S0002-9904-1944-08177-9/), Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. **50** (1944), 509--513
5. Q. I. Rahman: [*Inequalities for polynomials*](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1959-010-05/S0002-9939-1959-0108576-5/), Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **10** (1959), 800--806